# Rails 3.2 Heroku mail send error: SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, email, heroku

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and on Heroku Bamboo stack using Mailgun to send emails. I randomly get this error and have no idea what it means or where it comes from:

```
Started POST "/invites" for 67.250.49.100 at 2012-05-14 20:17:41 -0700
Sent mail to example@example.com (10147ms)

SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
    app/controllers/invites_controller.rb:43:in `invite_friend'
    app/controllers/invites_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Weirdly, sometimes it works and rarely it'll throw this error. Any ideas? I can't seem to regularly reproduce...